# Mutt - Oauth2.py - python3 support

Tags: mutt, python3, gmail

I was wondering if there was a version of oauth2.py [here](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/blob/master/python/oauth2.py) working in python3.

On my Manjaro, I got it to work by installing python2.But on a wsl install it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly this is the current state of gmail-oauth2-tools. There's opened pull request [Python3 compatibility update #12](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/pull/12) and seems untouched for more than 2 years.

There was recently opened issue for mutt and reopened for neomutt requesting vuilt-in oauth2 support:

- [mutt](https://github.com/muttmua/mutt/issues/1) unfortunately mutt uses gitlab for issues and there's no such issue right now.
- [neomutt](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/issues/1362)

Comment: thanks for the answer! - forcing python2 is not ideal but it works. I just had to avoid using openssl 1.1.1e / either downgrading or upgrading did the trick ;)